# How do I get Vim to compile my .tex file when executing :w?

Tags: external-command, filetype-tex

My writing routine is like this:

1. I edit a .tex file using vim
2. I go to the command line and I compile it using `pdflatex`. I find myself always saving the file with `:w` and immediately having to switch terminals to execute `pdflatex` (I use Ubuntu) to compile it.

This annoys me. I would like to make this more efficient so that I can manage to do both steps with a single shot. Is there a way to configure vim so that every time I save a `.tex` file with `:w`, the command `pdflatex` is executed automatically?

Comment: Your question is too broad right now. Do you already have a command to compile your latex files or are you looking for the `:Latekmk` command of [latex-box](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LaTeX-Box) plugin? Or are you looking for an [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand) to execute something on a file writing... Please clarify your question by indicating what you have searched and found so far.

Comment: @statox edited question

Comment: There are latex commands that auto-(re)compile your file(s) each time they change, outside & independent of Vim. Study that ;)

Comment: (I.e. you could start from something like `latexmk -pdf -pvc file.tex`)

Comment: @VanLaser may god bless you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't be so inefficient! Your time is valuable. Use the `vimtex` plugin offered by @lervag: [see here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/). You can control all of the plugins you install by using [`Vundle`](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) or any similar plugin manager (`vim-plug` is getting pretty popular).

Why waste your time installing `vimtex`? Great question!

#### Features

1. Continuous compilation using `latexmk` (please and thank you!)
2. Automatic warning/error notification using the vim quickfix window.
3. Forward and inverse search.
4. Support for a variety of PDF viewers.
5. Support for multi-file projects (I love this one) in conjunction with `gf` and `<ctrl-w>gf`.
6. commands that make things perform operations like `latexmk -C`.
7. It's under active development!
8. So much more!

Note, feature number 1 is the one which addresses your question. Each time you execute `:w` your document will be saved and automatically recompiled by `latexmk`. `latexmk` watches your LaTeX file for changes, automatically recompiling when changes are detected.

This post is not sponsored by or promoted by any developer or affiliate of the `vimtex` team (I'm just a lover).

Go be efficient!

Comment: I've installed vimtex, how do I use continuous compilation? If it should "just work" ... it's not doing much.

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 this stumped me as well. you need to use the command `:VimtexCompile` to start the continuous compilation.

Answer (score 8):

Adding this to my .vimrc works:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.tex silent! execute "!pdflatex % >/dev/null 2>&1" | redraw!
```

On all `.tex` files it will execute `pdflatex <filename>` upon `:w` without outputting anything in vim.

This is minimal and uses no plugins or extra programs.

Note: on compilation errors vim appears to hang, but pressing return solves this.

Comment: How can I see what the status is? I would want to see the live log being written into the stream by pdflatex

Answer (score 4):

If you use tpope's Dispatch plugin:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch you can run commands in the background.

I use this snippet to run xelatex on every save:

```
augroup latex
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter *.tex let b:dispatch='xelatex --output-directory=output %'
    autocmd BufWrite * Dispatch!
augroup end
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't configure Vim for that. Instead, I would use something like [entr](http://entrproject.org/):

```
$ ls foo.tex | entr <your command here>
```

Comment: The entr tool seems pretty interesting but in this case why would you recommend it more than an autocommand like `autocmd FileWritePost *.tex Latexmk`?

Comment: Because I prefer to use specialized tools.

Answer (score 3):

Since compiling a .tex file make take a few seconds, I prefer to do it in the background. There are two ways I've done this in the past: by running an asynchronous command using `job_start()`, and by using [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to send the compilation command to another terminal.

**1. using `job_start()`**

Add the following to your .vimrc:

```
function! RedrawScreen(channel)
    redraw!
endfunction

function! RunLatexmk()
    let tex_file = expand('%:p')    " current file
    let tex_cmd = 'latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -cd ' . tex_file
    let s:job = job_start(['/bin/sh', '-c', tex_cmd],
        \ {'close_cb': 'RedrawScreen'})
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite *.tex :call RunLatexmk()
```

I have defined the `RedrawScreen()` callback function because my screen often gets messed up when the `job_start()` job completes. Note that this uses `latexmk -pdf` which calls `pdflatex`. If instead you want to use `pdflatex` directly, you will have to first `cd` into the directory of the .tex file before you can call `pdflatex`.

**2. using tmux to send the `latexmk` command to another terminal**

Add the following to your .vimrc:

```
function! TmuxSend()
    let tex_file = expand('%:p')    " current file
    let tex_cmd = 'latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -cd ' . tex_file
    let tmux_cmd = 'tmux send-keys -t vim_output.0 "' . tex_cmd . '" ENTER'
    let output = system(tmux_cmd)   
endfunction

autocmd BufWrite *.tex :call TmuxSend()
```

Now, open another terminal and create a tmux session named "vim_output": `tmux new-session -s vim_output`. Now, when you save your file in Vim, the `latexmk` command will be run in the terminal you just created.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do exactly what you want:

Assuming you are using linux
(I do not know the Windows command)

To save and send to 'pdflatex':

```
:w | !pdflatex %
```

The '`%`' means 'the current file'
Notice that vertical bar `|`, it is necessary so that vim chains both commands one after another.

You can make a nice shortcut for this using '`cabbrev`'.
In your '`vimrc`' file, put:

```
cabbrev W w | !pdflatex %
```

This will make it so when you type "`:W` " (and make a space after),
it will autocorrect to

```
:w | !pdflatex %
```